# How to get number of visible characters inside a div(till its width), which has overflow text

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a div with text inside it
Eg

```html
    <div id="d1" style="width:50px;height:20px;background-color:tomato;">
            HelloHelloHelloHelloHelloHelloHelloHello
   </div>
```

How can i get the number of visible characters upto certain width(width of div) using jquery?

Comment: All the characters are visible in your example?

Comment: Sanket - As @Liam noted, you didn't include any `overflow` option. What are you using in your real situation? `overflow: none`? `overflow: auto`? `overflow: scroll`? Separately, is the text ever multiple lines? If so, what's the vertical overflow situation? Will there soemtimes be a scrollbar to worry about?

Comment: Pete's almost certainly right about the duplicate, but if not, edit and let us know.